# Is there a jquery plugin that does this better? Text drop down list (Not a menu)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

On the following page, I created a quick mock up of what I've been looking for. Here's the issue with my example:

1) It needs to be inline so it can be part of a sentence. Like.. Welcome to my blog, check out some of the [Categories]. Some more text after.

2) When the box examples, it should overlap the content below rather than push it down.

http://kyleetilley.name/examples/catbox/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog Design</title>

        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".catbox ul").hide();

            $(".catbox_toggle a").click(function()
            {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("catbox_active");
                $(".catbox ul").slideToggle();
            });
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        .catbox
        {
            width: 250px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 5px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

        .catbox ul
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="">
        <h1></h1>

        <div class="catbox">
            <div class="catbox_toggle"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#4">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
<html>
```

Optionally, if you tell me how to acomplish what I want to do with the code I have, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.catbox
{
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
}
.catbox ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
}
```

Comment: IE6/7 only supports inline block if the element is natively inline, which is an issue. Also, Zoom? That appears to be CSS 3 (is it supported by IE6?) but what is it actually doing in this example?

Comment: zoom:1;*display:inline; are for ie7 maybe ie6 inline-block incompatibility

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jQuery Menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) from [filament group](http://www.filamentgroup.com/) (the original creators of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)). [This](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/flat.php) seems to be exactly what you need.